# Will you please create an asset-backed-security tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I think it would be appropriate for this question: [Extension risk with IO bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100960/extension-risk-with-io-bonds/)

Comment: Good idea. Done.